# CSS won't display in Django Admin area after schema evolution and 'manage syncdb'

Tags: python, django

How do I keep Django Admin media from breaking every time the db schema changes?  Apparently something gets corrupted after I change the models and sync them to the db, because that's when it stops displaying Admin area CSS. I wish I knew what was being corrupted.

The problem is not in Django itself, because when I try a different local project the CSS of its admin area works.

I was able to fix admin media on the project in question by having MySQL drop the tables and then running 'manage syncdb'. But that was with empty tables. It will be a real pain if schema evolution with data already in tables breaks it. Why is this happening?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'ecomstore.catalog',
)
```

Update: I'm using the dev server on Windows Vista.  Django 1.3, Py2.7.1.  Also, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with model-db syncing as it broke again w/o me making any changes whatsoever.  It also doesn't seem to be limited to CSS but JavaScript ad others as well.  I'm doing the example from Beginning Django Ecommerce.

Comment: Have you modify MEDIA_ROOT (STATIC and so on) in your project? If yes, try to undo this changes and then string by string edit it, inspecting admin panel. So you will understand where was error, which ruins CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an app called `media` in your site? It is probably conflicting with the urls that django uses for its admin madia.

Could you post the list of apps and models?

Comment: There is no such app in my project.